# Networking and Tcp/IP

Tags: networking, tcp

currently I am learning about network protocol layers and other things but i could not understand the difference between system **mac address** and **ip** address .why do we need **ip** address, we got mac address which is unique.what is the use of system **IP** address? .i have already tried.could not find the solution.

Comment: IPs are used for routing. When you leave a network and enter a new one, chances are, your IP-address will have changed. IPs do *not* uniquely identify a device, only a point in an active Internet connection. MAC addresses don't, since they are uniquely tied to one network card. Keep in mind that they can be spoofed.

Comment: @FynnMazurkiewicz, you have it backwards. The IP paradigm is that IP addresses are end-to-end addresses, but MAC addresses are only relevant or seen on the LAN where the host with that MAC address is connected. The frame containing the MAC addresses is stripped off and lost at a layer-3 hop (router), but the packet containing the IP addresses is not.

Comment: @RonMaupin I don't see how my comment contradicts your comment. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @FynnMazurkiewicz, you are saying the IP address changes, but the MAC address does not. The IP paradigm is that the IP address is the same, end-to-end, but the MAC address will be different if the packet must cross LANs.

Comment: @RonMaupin I'm saying that, from a device's perspective.

Answer (score -1):

MAC addresses are used by *some* layer-2 protocols (IEEE LAN) for communications on a LAN. Not all layer-2 protocols use MAC addresses, and of those that do, some use 48-bit MAC addresses and some use 64-bit MAC addresses. To communicate between LANs you need a layer-3 protocol (IPv4, IPX, IPv6, AppleTalk, etc).

Routers route packets between network at layer-3, so they strip off the layer-2 frame, which would contain any MAC addresses, to get to the layer-3 packet. A router will then look at the layer-3 address to find a match in its routing table. If it doesn't find a match, it discards the packet, otherwise, it will switch the packet to the interface toward the destination network, build a new frame for the new interface, and forward the packet.

Layer-3 (e.g. IPv4) addresses are end-to-end addresses, across any number of links/LANs that a packet may need to travel, but layer-2 (e.g. MAC) addresses are only relevant or even seen on the LAN where the host with that layer-2 address is connected.

Layer-4 (e.g. TCP) addresses (also called ports for some layer-4 protocols) connect application processes.

Think about it this way:

On a LAN, layer-2 in the source host communicates with layer-2 in the destination host. Layer-3 in the source host communicates with layer-3 in the destination host, regardless of the LAN. Layer-4 in the source host communicates with layer-4 in the destination host, allowing application-to-application communications.